# How to properly handle type for es6 Map<K,V> functions when using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a class like this:

```
export class Broker<T> implements BrokerContract<T> {

  topicToSubscribersMap: Map<string, Set<Subscriber<T>>>;
                            .
                            .
                            .

  public registerSubscriber(topic: string, subscriber: Subscriber<T>): void {

        if (this.topicToSubscribersMap.get(topic)) {
            let currentSubscribers: Set<Subscriber<T>> = this.topicToSubscribersMap.get(topic);
        }
  }


                           .
                           .
}
```

In the function `registerSubscriber` when I try to get value from the map Typescript complains that we cannot assign type of `V | undefined` to `V` since `get` method on `Map` returns `V | undefined`.

Now, I know that I can do this -

```
let currentSubscribers: Set<Subscriber<T>> = <Set<Subscriber<T>>>this.topicToSubscribersMap.get(topic);
```

Or this -

```
let currentSubscribers: Set<Subscriber<T>> = this.topicToSubscribersMap.get(topic) as Set<Subscriber<T>>;
```

But my concern is why is this even required when I am already checking for `undefined` in the enclosing `if` condition?

Also, since this is the signature itself of `get` method of `Map` to return `V | undefined` type, and assuming this situation might come up generally most often with it - what is the best  way to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript isn't clever enough to narrow the results of a function call because the call is assumed to not be pure (i.e. it might return a different value on subsequent calls with the same parameters)

If instead you assign to a variable first:

```
const topic = this.topicToSubscribersMap.get(topic);
if (topic){
    // topic is narrowed to Set<Subscriber<T>>
}
```

Comment: In your example, we are inferring type from return type of function call. What if we wanted to declare all such variables before hand with some types, to ensure that they get what we expect ?